# Converting EC2 to local VM using VMware Converter, bluescreening

Tags: amazon-ec2, virtual-machines, vmware-workstation, vmware-converter

I initially wanted to copy locally an EC2 windows server instance and bring in to Hyper-V but have decided VMware workstation might be easier. None-the-less each method I try results in the exact same issue with a failure on storport.sys and bluescreening; in safemode it fails on ClassPNP. I have followed [these](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1018015) VM conversion directions with no luck (I do not know how to proceed with step 5, but either way the VM still bluescreens). How can I copy this instance locally to be run as a VM.

Here's the specifics:
Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit
VMware vCenter Converter 5.01

Local machine:
VMware Workstation 8.05
Windows 8 64bit

Comment: I just noticed the directions specify converter 4, I'll see if I can find that version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](http://communities.vmware.com/message/2016104#2016104) response which apparently works for my situation, I am going to double check and see if it works and solves the hardware driver issue.

Update: I was able to solve this by deleting the rhelscsi driver found in C:\windows\system32\drivers, I did this from the system restore command line.

Additional optional workaround:

Steps involved:

> select command prompt and type regedit select HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE hive
>   on the left from File menu select "Load Hive..." command and browse to
>   C:\Windows\System32\config directory and select SYSTEM file enter a
>   key name when prompted (e. g. p2v) find the key you specified in the
>   previous step under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and navigate to
>   ControlSet001\services for each of rhelfltr, rhelnet and rhelscsi
>   services you should select the service, locate the "Start" value on
>   the right and change it to 4 (service disabled) select the key created
>   earlier, unload the registry hive and restart the operating system